# Why can't I pass array literals into fwrite?

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, fwrite, literals

```
fwrite({0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d, 0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1f, 0xf3, 0xff, 0x61, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x8a, 0x49, 0x44, 0x41, 0x54, 0x38, 0x8d, 0xa5, 0x93, 0xb1, 0x72, 0xd4, 0x30, 0x10, 0x86, 0xbf, 0x95, 0xad, 0xcc, 0xc4, 0x30, 0xa4, 0xb9, 0xe6, 0x68, 0x68, 0xd3, 0x50, 0xf3, 0x42, 0xbc, 0x0e, 0xcf, 0xc3, 0x0c, 0x1d, 0x33, 0x69, 0x68, 0xa8, 0xaf, 0x09, 0xc5, 0x51, 0x98, 0xc2, 0x8d, 0x13, 0x10, 0xb6, 0x25, 0xad, 0x28, 0x24, 0xeb, 0x7c, 0xb9, 0x50, 0x45, 0x33, 0x1e, 0x6b, 0x77, 0x76, 0xff, 0x7f, 0xff, 0xdd, 0x95, 0x70, 0xf7, 0x25, 0xf1, 0x82, 0xd3, 0x02, 0x7c, 0x7c, 0xfb, 0x0e, 0x80, 0xce, 0x18, 0x76, 0xad, 0xc5, 0x8a, 0xe0, 0x53, 0xc6, 0x5d, 0xff, 0x56, 0xa4, 0xda, 0xf9, 0x53, 0x3e, 0xfd, 0xfc, 0x41, 0x4b, 0x4a, 0xdc, 0x5e, 0x77, 0x15, 0x71, 0x4d, 0xb6, 0xc5, 0xf6, 0xaa, 0xd9, 0x6f, 0x0c, 0x5e, 0x15, 0xa7, 0xca, 0x18, 0x03, 0x63, 0x0c, 0xa5, 0x02, 0xd3, 0x5c, 0xa0, 0x5b, 0x11, 0x3a, 0x63, 0xb2, 0x2d, 0x82, 0x8b, 0x11, 0x17, 0x63, 0x25, 0xd8, 0xb5, 0x96, 0x5d, 0x9b, 0x29, 0x0c, 0x49, 0x4f, 0xac, 0x22, 0x78, 0xcd, 0xb6, 0x53, 0xad, 0xe5, 0x77, 0x4d, 0x73, 0x46, 0xe0, 0x34, 0xe2, 0x34, 0x42, 0x4a, 0xb9, 0x07, 0x56, 0x04, 0x2b, 0xc2, 0xe1, 0xaf, 0x03, 0x60, 0xff, 0x44, 0xf7, 0x36, 0x06, 0xc0, 0xe9, 0xc9, 0x6f, 0xb2, 0x43, 0x71, 0x31, 0xb2, 0xb7, 0x57, 0xec, 0xed, 0x55, 0xd5, 0xb7, 0x56, 0xf0, 0xf4, 0x0e, 0xe4, 0x18, 0xd5, 0x5c, 0x41, 0xd5, 0x1b, 0x23, 0xbd, 0x5f, 0x0a, 0xcb, 0x72, 0xc1, 0xde, 0x95, 0x7e, 0x39, 0x8d, 0x15, 0xc0, 0x20, 0x39, 0x79, 0x6d, 0xca, 0x87, 0xd7, 0x6f, 0x2e, 0x66, 0x9d, 0x75, 0x2b, 0x43, 0xf0, 0xf4, 0x7e, 0xe1, 0xb8, 0xcc, 0xdc, 0x4f, 0x13, 0x04, 0x4f, 0x4b, 0xd1, 0x75, 0xd2, 0x17, 0x79, 0xdf, 0xbd, 0xaa, 0x4d, 0xdd, 0x56, 0xb1, 0x05, 0x73, 0x31, 0x72, 0x37, 0xfc, 0xca, 0x12, 0x6e, 0x9a, 0x16, 0x2b, 0xc2, 0xed, 0x75, 0x77, 0x36, 0xca, 0xad, 0x76, 0x9f, 0x14, 0x2b, 0x06, 0x50, 0xbc, 0x2a, 0xc7, 0x65, 0x86, 0xa6, 0xc9, 0x15, 0xfc, 0xaf, 0xdb, 0xdb, 0x64, 0x80, 0x7e, 0x99, 0x39, 0x4c, 0x8e, 0xfb, 0x69, 0xa2, 0xf7, 0x33, 0x50, 0x56, 0x79, 0x9d, 0xc4, 0x73, 0x00, 0x79, 0xe6, 0xca, 0xe0, 0x3d, 0x87, 0xc9, 0xf1, 0xed, 0xf7, 0x03, 0x83, 0xf7, 0x15, 0xb4, 0xdd, 0x06, 0xfa, 0x94, 0xb8, 0x69, 0xda, 0x33, 0xe6, 0x35, 0xf9, 0xfb, 0x9f, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xbf, 0xd4, 0x2d, 0x05, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x7c, 0x7e, 0x0b, 0x63, 0x0c, 0x79, 0xc7, 0x43, 0x60, 0x0c, 0xa1, 0x6e, 0xe6, 0x76, 0xf3, 0x86, 0xe0, 0x39, 0xce, 0x13, 0xe3, 0x32, 0x43, 0x61, 0x07, 0x10, 0xbe, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0xfe, 0x39, 0x97, 0xf5, 0xad, 0xc7, 0x14, 0x3b, 0xa5, 0x33, 0x80, 0x7f, 0xf7, 0xfa, 0x32, 0x22, 0x9c, 0x84, 0x99, 0xd5, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x49, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x44, 0xae, 0x42, 0x60, 0x82}, 1, 451, DiamondBlockTextureFile);
```

This code is what I tried and the too few arguments and expression expected before the opening curly bracket of the array literal are the errors I get

Proceeding is what I want to know how to do

Comment: Make it a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) and see if it works that way.

Comment: Add `(uint8_t [])` before opening curly brace

Comment: Don't do like that, it's totally meaningless without any context. Instead create a proper array, named with a descriptive name, and with comments explaining what the data is for and what it does. What looks like random number is just noise for anyone reading your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Merely listing values inside braces does not create an array.

When defining an array, you can list initial values inside braces. In this syntax, the list of initial values is merely a list of initial values—it is not an array; it is just the syntax for listing the values to initialize the array with.

You can create an “on the fly” with a *compound literal*, which is a type name inside parentheses followed by a brace-enclosed list of initializers:

```
fwrite((const unsigned char []) { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, … }, 1, 451, DiamondBlockTextureFile);
```

This is generally not good practice, particularly since the size the array, 451, can be easily miscalculated, or it might not be updated when somebody updates the elements in the array, and so on.

Better practice would be to create a named array to hold the data, if it is used only briefly:

```
static const unsigned char Temporary[] = { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, … };
fwrite(Temporary, 1, sizeof Temporary, DiamondBlockTextureFile);
```

Comment: Would also suggest making the temporary `const`, to make it clear to readers of the code that this data is read-only.

Comment: `static` should also be considered, depending on the system.  On any system with limited stack space, creating the array on the stack could cause problems.

Comment: Isn't that just casting the literal into an unsigned char []

Comment: A list of values in braces is not a literal. There is nothing in the C grammar for it alone. It could not be, because there is no way of telling whether `{ 1, 'a', 2.0 }` should be a literal of type `char []`, `int []`, `double []`, or something else. The grammar and other rules for C literals are specified in C 2018 6.5.2 1 and 6.5.2.5, and a compound literal has the form `( type-name ) { initializer-list }`, with an optional comma at the end of the list. This not a cast; it is a special syntax for compound literals.